# How do you call a method in a .class File

Tags: java

So say you have a class file (No source code). And the only thing you need to know is there is a public static String[] getBookings() in that class file. How do you call that method to your main program?

Comment: It doesn't matter that there's no source code; have you tried calling `YourClass.getBookings()` from your main method?

Comment: Oh Thank you!. I got it working. Thanks a lot :)

Answer (score 0):

If you use any 3rd party JAR, you'll have a .class file without .java source.  That's common.

How do you do it?  Easy - instantiate an instance and call the method if it's not a static method; call it on the class if it is.

```
public static void main(String [] args) {
    com.foo.Bar bar = new com.foo.Bar();
    String [] bookings = bar.getBookings();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Add the class file to the same place as your .java files and try calling the method in your .java file.

Answer (score 0):

you can use javap command on windows command line or unix shell if you have Java_Home/BIN in your classpath

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/tools/windows/javap.html